# Transparent panel can't receive WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

In my c# winform project, I put a panel in a form. The panel's BackColor is the same as the form's TransparencyKey, so it looks 'transparent'.

I want the form to be moved when clicking/dragging inside the 'transparent' panel. So I override the panel's WndProc as below:

```
public class UnclickablePanel : Panel {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) {  // WM_NCHITTEST
            m.Result = new IntPtr(-1);
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the panel returns "-1"(transparent) and then the form can handle the mouse down/up/move events.

It works fine in Win7 with Aero theme. But if win xp or win7 + basic theme, the panel can't receive WM_NCHITTEST at all. It just click through the form.

Any solution or workaround?